# Create 301 redirect in windows server

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, http-redirect

I use **URL Rewrite** section in IIS manager to create a `redirect 301` for my website and redirect **search engines** and users from `DomainName.com` to `www.DomainName.com`. after creating a rule for this purpose in IIS, it generates the following code in `web.config` file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="redirect 301" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^DomainName\.com.*" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="www.{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Is there any miskate in my code, or I must use another method for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in [Scott Guthrie post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx) : Scenario 4: Canonical Host Names,
for this purpose must I create `canonical domain name` rule and write my primary url to redirect other forms of urls to that.
and the code in `web.config` file is this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domainName\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainName.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```